# My app runs properly on the simulator, but crashes on my ios 13.2 iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My app runs properly on the simulator, but crashes on my iOS 13.2 iPhone when it is about to run on the device.  Also the textfield become black. Why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: where you find crashed please wrote code

Comment: Your TextField becomes black probably because you use dark theme on your device. please share more information about your crash

Answer (score 0):

If you have update xCode to 11.2 then according to [this discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/125287) it could be a new bug, which occurs when using `UITextView` created in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Your textfield becomes black because by default the background color of text field component is "Default" color, that is it changes according to the iPhone theme, you will have to explicitly set the background of the textfield so that it is consistent on both themes. The crash seems to be a bug , and a screenshot of the same will help.